# To-Do List, and at 5 elements checked to show a button

Tags: javascript, html, button

How can I make a To-Do List, and at 5 elements checked to show a button?
I have already done the To-Do list (in HTML and JavaScript - my code below ), but I don't know how can I write a code to show a button at 5 elements checked.
My JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sd355qxp
My code (in HTML and JavaScript) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tomo.css">
        <title>TOMO</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>TOMO</h1>
        <center>
            <div id="todo-app">
                <label class="todo-label" for="new-todo">What do you have to do today?</label>
                <input type="text" id="new-todo" class="todo-input" placeholder="english homework">
                <ul id="todo-list" class="count-this"></ul>
                <div id="todo-stats"></div>
            </div>
        </center>
        <script type="text/x-template" id="todo-item-template">
    <div class="todo-view">
        <input type="checkbox" class="todo-checkbox" {checked}>
        <span class="todo-content" tabindex="0">{text}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="todo-edit">
        <input type="text" class="todo-input" value="{text}">
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="todo-remove" title="Remove this task">
        <span class="todo-remove-icon"></span>
    </a>
</script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="todo-stats-template">
    <span class="todo-count">
        <span class="todo-remaining">{numRemaining}</span>
        <span class="todo-remaining-label">{remainingLabel}</span> left.
    </span>

    <a href="#" class="todo-clear">
        Clear <span class="todo-done">{numDone}</span>
        completed <span class="todo-done-label">{doneLabel}</span>
    </a>
</script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>

<script>
YUI().use('event-focus', 'json', 'model', 'model-list', 'view', function (Y) {
    var TodoAppView, TodoList, TodoModel, TodoView;

TodoModel = Y.TodoModel = Y.Base.create('todoModel', Y.Model, [], {
    sync: LocalStorageSync('todo'),
    toggleDone: function () {
        this.set('done', !this.get('done')).save();
    }
}, {
    ATTRS: {
        done: {value: false},
        text: {value: ''}
    }
});

TodoList = Y.TodoList = Y.Base.create('todoList', Y.ModelList, [], {
    model: TodoModel,
    sync: LocalStorageSync('todo'),
    done: function () {
        return this.filter(function (model) {
            return model.get('done');
        });
    },
    remaining: function () {
        return this.filter(function (model) {
            return !model.get('done');
        });
    }
});

TodoAppView = Y.TodoAppView = Y.Base.create('todoAppView', Y.View, [], {
    events: {
        '#new-todo': {keypress: 'createTodo'},
        '.todo-clear': {click: 'clearDone'},
        '.todo-item': {
            mouseover: 'hoverOn',
            mouseout : 'hoverOff'
        }
    },
    template: Y.one('#todo-stats-template').getHTML(),
    initializer: function () {
        var list = this.todoList = new TodoList();
        list.after('add', this.add, this);
        list.after('reset', this.reset, this);
        list.after(['add', 'reset', 'remove', 'todoModel:doneChange'],
                this.render, this);
        list.load();
    },
    render: function () {
        var todoList = this.todoList,
            stats    = this.get('container').one('#todo-stats'),
            numRemaining, numDone;
        if (todoList.isEmpty()) {
            stats.empty();
            return this;
        }
        numDone      = todoList.done().length;
        numRemaining = todoList.remaining().length;
        stats.setHTML(Y.Lang.sub(this.template, {
            numDone       : numDone,
            numRemaining  : numRemaining,
            doneLabel     : numDone === 1 ? 'task' : 'tasks',
            remainingLabel: numRemaining === 1 ? 'task' : 'tasks'
        }));
        if (!numDone) {
            stats.one('.todo-clear').remove();
        }

        return this;
    },
    add: function (e) {
        var view = new TodoView({model: e.model});

        this.get('container').one('#todo-list').append(
            view.render().get('container')
        );
    },
    clearDone: function (e) {
        var done = this.todoList.done();

        e.preventDefault();
        this.todoList.remove(done, {silent: true});
        Y.Array.each(done, function (todo) {
            todo.destroy({remove: true});
        });
        this.render();
    },
    createTodo: function (e) {
        var inputNode, value;

        if (e.keyCode === 13) { // enter key
            inputNode = this.get('inputNode');
            value     = Y.Lang.trim(inputNode.get('value'));

            if (!value) { return; }
            this.todoList.create({text: value});

            inputNode.set('value', '');
        }
    },
    hoverOff: function (e) {
        e.currentTarget.removeClass('todo-hover');
    },
    hoverOn: function (e) {
        e.currentTarget.addClass('todo-hover');
    },
    reset: function (e) {
        var fragment = Y.one(Y.config.doc.createDocumentFragment());

        Y.Array.each(e.models, function (model) {
            var view = new TodoView({model: model});
            fragment.append(view.render().get('container'));
        });

        this.get('container').one('#todo-list').setHTML(fragment);
    }
}, {
    ATTRS: {
        container: {
            valueFn: function () {
                return '#todo-app';
            }
        },
        inputNode: {
            valueFn: function () {
                return Y.one('#new-todo');
            }
        }
    }
});

TodoView = Y.TodoView = Y.Base.create('todoView', Y.View, [], {
    containerTemplate: '<li class="todo-item"/>',
    events: {
        '.todo-checkbox': {click: 'toggleDone'},
        '.todo-content': {
            click: 'edit',
            focus: 'edit'
        },
        '.todo-input'   : {
            blur    : 'save',
            keypress: 'enter'
        },
        '.todo-remove': {click: 'remove'}
    },
    template: Y.one('#todo-item-template').getHTML(),

    initializer: function () {
        var model = this.get('model');
        model.after('change', this.render, this);

        model.after('destroy', function () {
            this.destroy({remove: true});
        }, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        var container = this.get('container'),
            model     = this.get('model'),
            done      = model.get('done');

        container.setHTML(Y.Lang.sub(this.template, {
            checked: done ? 'checked' : '',
            text   : model.getAsHTML('text')
        }));

        container[done ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('todo-done');
        this.set('inputNode', container.one('.todo-input'));

        return this;
    },
    edit: function () {
        this.get('container').addClass('editing');
        this.get('inputNode').focus();
    },
    enter: function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) { 
            Y.one('#new-todo').focus();
        }
    },
    remove: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.constructor.superclass.remove.call(this);
        this.get('model').destroy({'delete': true});
    },

    save: function () {
        this.get('container').removeClass('editing');
        this.get('model').set('text', this.get('inputNode').get('value')).save();
    },

    toggleDone: function () {
        this.get('model').toggleDone();
    }
});

function LocalStorageSync(key) {
    var localStorage;

    if (!key) {
        Y.error('No storage key specified.');
    }

    if (Y.config.win.localStorage) {
        localStorage = Y.config.win.localStorage;
    }

    var data = Y.JSON.parse((localStorage && localStorage.getItem(key)) || '{}');
    function destroy(id) {
        var modelHash;

        if ((modelHash = data[id])) {
            delete data[id];
            save();
        }

        return modelHash;
    }
    function generateId() {
        var id = '',
            i  = 4;

        while (i--) {
            id += (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0)
                    .toString(16).substring(1);
        }

        return id;
    }
    function get(id) {
        return id ? data[id] : Y.Object.values(data);
    }
    function save() {
        localStorage && localStorage.setItem(key, Y.JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    function set(model) {
        var hash        = model.toJSON(),
            idAttribute = model.idAttribute;

        if (!Y.Lang.isValue(hash[idAttribute])) {
            hash[idAttribute] = generateId();
        }

        data[hash[idAttribute]] = hash;
        save();

        return hash;
    }
    return function (action, options, callback) {
        var isModel = Y.Model && this instanceof Y.Model;

        switch (action) {
        case 'create': // intentional fallthru
        case 'update':
            callback(null, set(this));
            return;

        case 'read':
            callback(null, get(isModel && this.get('id')));
            return;

        case 'delete':
            callback(null, destroy(isModel && this.get('id')));
            return;
        }
    };
}
new TodoAppView();

});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should really tag yui in question...

Answer (score 1):

Can you use jQuery?

```
$(".todo-checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(".todo-checkbox:checked").length > 4){
        $("#yourButton").show();
    }
});
```